# Why does a question like "What are all the possible types of output from a computer" deemed unfit here?

Tags: discussion

In the past, I asked the following or similar question here:

> ## What are all the possible types of output from a computer?
>
> I am trying to understand what are the general types of output of a
>   computer.
>  I assume the following described general types of output
>   are the only ones in the cosmos, but I might be wrong:
>
> - **Screened Raw Data:** Output such as a document available only to be read but not edited (as when opened with a reading-only "viewer"
>     program)
> - **Screened Interface:** Output such as a document available to be both read and edited (as when opened with a text editor)
> - **Spatial Change:** Output such as the result of a computerized machine, or alternatively, a computer embedded system (such as a robot
>     and maybe also quantum computer or some physical yet non material
>     computer of some sort)
>
> <sub>A similar try is defining what are the only possible ways to
>   input data into computer, such as with CLUI, TUI, GUI and possibly
>   other methods.</sub>
>
> **What are all the possible types of output from a computer?**
>
> That is to ask: Is there a consensus among computer scientists and/or UX researchers
>   about what are the general types of output of a computer?

I recall that the question was closed and to save it from being automatically deleted I published it in UX SE and got an answer which I accepted:

- https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/130346/general-types-of-output-of-a-computer

**Why does a question like "What are all the possible types of output from a computer" deemed unfit here?**

Comment: It reads as if you were more interested in real-world computing machines than in computer _science_.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a philosophical formulation of the question maybe.

I'd answer it as:

Like in every encoder-decoder system, the output of the computer is processed data encoded and sent as a signal to the decoding reciever. A signal can be classified into 5 categories, one for each of the 5 senses which we use as perception tools. A multiclass perceptron can be used to model the classification process of the brain.